# What is the best approach to reuse similar method in multiple Services that use similar objects?

Tags: java, spring, generics, design-patterns

I have several services that have the same method that is called by a Scheduler. This is one example of one service.

```
@Service
public class MyService1 {

     @Autowired
     private MyLocalMapper1 localMapper1;
     
     @Autowired
     private MyLocalRepository1 localRepository1;

     @Autowired
     private MyExternalMapper1 externalMapper1;
     
     @Autowired
     private MyExternalRepository1 externalRepository1;
  

     public void startProcess() {
          //I use the mappers and the repositories in here
     }
}
```

I have 15 services exactly similars to this one but every service has a specific mappers (e.g. MyLocalMapper2, MyLocalMapper3, etc...) and also repositories.

e.g

```
 @Service
 public class MyService2 {

     @Autowired
     private MyLocalMapper2 localMapper2;
     
     @Autowired
     private MyLocalRepository2 localRepository2;

     @Autowired
     private MyExternalMapper2 externalMapper2;
     
     @Autowired
     private MyExternalRepository2 externalRepository2;
  

     public void startProcess() {
          //I use the mappers and the repositories in here
     }
}
```

Is there any design pattern which allows to reuse the code inside startProcess method taking into account that the objects it uses are different in every service?

I thought in creating interfaces for every object such as: LocalMapperInterface, LocalRepositoryInterface, etc.. and pass it to a single method with all those interfaces as parameters but not sure if that is the best approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to know more about the startProcess method - does it do the same type of things in all the services?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, maybe "Template Method Pattern" is a feasible method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract class like following and extend it in all the 15 services provided that the mappers and repos have common parent class which you can use here in the abstract class:

```
    public abstract class ScheduledService {
      public void startProcess() {
        LocalMapper localMapper = getLocalMapper();
        LocalRepository localRepo = getLocalRepository();
        ExternalMapper externalMapper = getExternalMapper();
        ExternalRepository externalRepo = getExternalRepository();
        // use above objects here!!
      }

      public LocalMapper getLocalMapper();

      public LocalRepository getLocalRepository();

      public ExternalMapper getExternalMapper();

      public ExternalRepository getExternalRepository();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to look for common things in repositories and mappers. Because if there are differences, then whatever design may be applied, it will result in the violation of Liskov's substitution principle. :( If all the methods of mappers can be pulled up into a common interface, then pass a Mapper interface into all the classes. It will automatically turn it into a Template method :)

Then do the same with Repositories, but if any one of those impls are uncommon, then just leave it as it is.

If both interfaces can be extracted, then look for startProcess method. If such is a case that you have to create 100s of services just because of the different combinations of mappers and repositories, and you have to use different numbers of mappers and repositories, then that would be the case for Decorator pattern. But if the startProcess method is uncommon, then just leave it at that - as that will be over-engineered.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MyService {
  @Autowired
  protected Mapper mapper;

  @Autowired
  protected Repository repository;

  //now becomes a Template method
  //if can't be turned into template method, then leave the method abstract instead
  public void startProcess() {
    ..
    something = mapper.map(..);
    ..
    repositoryResult = repository.doSomething(..);
  }
}
```